# Problem with @Override annotation

Tags: java, overriding

I am making a Java application similar to that of the Banko applet. I was coming along just fine when I hit the "public void init()" method. When I was finished, everything compiled except for that. It told me to add an @Override annotation. I tried that, but whenever I do, regardless of where I put it, the compiler fails with the following error:

cannot find symbol

symbol: class Overrides

location: class aBomb.Bomb

I have no idea what could be preventing the application from executing properly. :|
If you find something in the code I have written below that you think should be changed, please tell me. I'm relatively new to Java :(
Code:

```
public void init() {
    BorderLayout border = new BorderLayout();
    setLayout(border);

    JPanel top = new JPanel();
    JLabel moneyLabel = new JLabel("Money : $");
    moneyField = new JTextField("", 8);
    moneyField.setEditable(false);
    JLabel foundLabel = new JLabel("Found: ");
    foundField = new JTextField("", 8);
    foundField.setEditable(false);

    restart = new JButton("Restart");
    restart.addActionListener(this);
    top.add(moneyLabel);
    top.add(moneyField);
    top.add(foundLabel);
    top.add(foundField);
    top.add(restart);
    add(top, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    board = new Board(this, ROW_COUNT, COLUMN_COUNT, BOMB_COUNT);
    add(board, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    setup();
    setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: what kind of class is this in?

Comment: Where did you try adding the annotation?

Comment: @Anon I tried putting the @Override before the public void init and below it

Comment: @codethis What do you mean by class (Im sort of new :( )

Comment: Your error mentions "Overrides" but you talk about "Override". Which one is it?

Comment: this function is part of a larger file I would assume.  Is there a line at the top of the file with the word 'class' in it?  If this function is part of a class and it already exists in the base class, you would need to override the original function.

Comment: Both, really. @Overrides if I put it in front of the public void init. @Override if I put it anywhere else.

Comment: @codethis yes there is a line defining the class. Are you suggesting that I do "public class Bomb" and then "@Override" below that?

Comment: [`@Override`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html) is a defined annotation class in Java. `@Overrides` is not. Hence, the compile error.

Comment: is it 'public class Bomb extends *' where '*' is some other class?

Comment: @Santa So instead of @Overrides public void init() do @Override public void init()?

Comment: @codethis I'm not sure I understand what you are asking

Comment: However, there is another problem. I cannot publish the applet on the web. I don't know why. I know the syntax of the <applet> HTML markup, but I need help figuring out why it won't work.

Comment: I am going to rollback your edit because: 1) You have effectively deleted your original question, making all answers useless. 2) Your new question can not be answered because it fails to provide the necessary detail, such as the source code you are trying to run.

Comment: @meriton I am sorry. The problem is now resolved as I have created a new post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, it would **really** help if you'd included at least the class definition (the "public class..." part.)

I'm guessing that you have a class named aBomb which extends from Applet:

```
public class aBomb extends Applet {
//...
    // Here's the init method; the @Override goes
    // immediately before the declaration.
    @Override
    public void init() {
//...
};
```

The error message looks as if you misspelled `@Override` as `@Overrides`.

Comment: @user544133 Then please accept the answer as the solution! :)

Answer (score 2):

The annotation class you are trying to use is `java.lang.Override`.  This is imported by default.

Check the following:

- The annotation is `@Override` but the error message says that you spelled it as `@Overrides`.  Check your source code for a spelling / typing error.
- You are using Java 5.0 or later.
- You have not used the `-source` or `-target` compilation switches to compile for an older version of Java.
- You are not using `-bootclasspath` (or whatever) to compile against a non-standard class library.

Answer (score 1):

The annotation is called `@Override`, not `@Overrides`. It goes in front of the overriding method, like:

```
@Override
public void init() {
   ...
```